# How to convert a string containing nanoseconds to datetime in Spark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I am having a timestamp field as below in my JSON file.

`"CreateDateTime":"2019-04-03T02:02:12.6475327Z"`

When I cast to timestamp, I am able to see the correct value but the 7th digit is truncated.

`jsonDF.select(col("CreateDateTime").cast("timestamp")).show(truncate = False)`

```
+--------------------------+
|CreateDateTime            |
+--------------------------+
|2019-04-03 02:02:12.647532|
+--------------------------+
```

I want to get the same value as it appears in source in timestamp format (without T's and Z's). Can you please suggest.

Comment: The timestamp format only supports 6 digits.

Comment: @pault, Is there a way to get the same value as in source but in timestamp type?